# How do I set the date format for a Label Widget?

Tags: google-apps-script

I don't understand how to put the pieces together.

The script:

- Gets a data range from a google spreadsheet.
- Filters the data into a new array
- Adds data to a widget label.

Dates are displayed as 'Tue Oct 06 1942 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)' and i want 'Oct 6, 1942.'

How do I use:

```
Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
```

with

```
grid.setWidget(i +1, 2, ui.createLabel(mapData[i][3]));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've answered your question yourself

Use

```
var dt = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "MM dd, yyyy");
grid.setWidget(i+1, 2, ui.createLabel(dt));
```